# Auto refresh after few seconds on submit button pressed

Tags: wordpress

How could I add a redirect to my front page after the submit button is pressed on woo commerce?

I allowed file attachement to my reviews, it takes a while to refresh the page altough the attachement is already uploaded.

I wish to add a refresh or return to homepage automaticly after 10 secondes or so.

I did found hook to do that after comment is send but i m looking to add this at the press of the submit button.

How could i do that?

thankkks a lot///

Answer (score 0):

You can use an **jquery** script to make this work. Using **jquery** you can set the time interval and event for refreshing or redirecting to home after pressing submit button.
E.g. [jquery and javascript refresh](https://www.js-tutorials.com/javascript-tutorial/how-to-reload-and-refresh-page-using-jquery-and-javascript/)